# nestjs - dynamic validation typeorm

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm, node.js-typeorm, typeorm-validation

I want to create a form builder and I have dynamics fields and validation. for example, sometimes I have fields like this

```
@IsNotEmpty()
 name: string

@IsNotEmpty()
@IsEmail()
email: string

@IsNotEmpty()
@Length(11)
mobile: string
```

and sometimes I have fields like this:

```
@IsNotEmpty()
name: string
@IsNumber()
age: number
```

How can I handle it?

Comment: These are not from TypeOrm, you want to do the same using TypeOrm in your database defintions ?

Comment: no, I want to do this before the database.

Comment: So you'r using the right method with the class-validator package, maybe juste use the pipe to select one or another in input as DynamicsFields1 | DynamicsFields2.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand your question but I think you need to add `IsOptional()` on stuff that you won't check unless they have value, on the other hand you can use `ValidateIf()` on fields  depends on others,

```
      @ValidateIf((object) => object.name!= undefined)
      @IsNumber()
      age: number
```